# Interface list vs. implemented list

Tags: c#

In my understanding we use interfaces to let the user also use custom list(which need to implement the IList for example).

In many code exercises I see something like this.

`IList<string> interfaceList = new List<string>();`

My question is. Isn't the following list as capable as the first one since both get implemented by List. If yes why use IList when not using custom Lists?

`List<string> normalList = new List<string>();`

Comment: Suppose you have a method parameter of type `List<string>`. That can *only* be called by someone who has a `List<string>`. What if they actually have an `ArraySegment<string>` for example? They can't use your method without copying the array segment to a list...

Comment: So yes, in your specific example, assuming you never need to assign a new value to the variable, it's fine to declare the variable as `List<string>`. But if you declare it as the interface type you avoid accidentally using things that are *only* in `List<string>`, which may be important if you want to leave yourself easily able to move to a different implementation later.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: `List<T>` has some specific methods like `ConvertAll`, `AddRange` which are not available to `IList<T>`. If you're gonna use those you shouldn't declare as `IList<T>`.

Comment: A disadvantage of `IList<T>` is that arrays pretend implementing it but throw an exception if you try to call `list.Add(x)`. This violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the following list as capable as the first one

It is as there is no difference between the LISTS - both are crated with the same statement.

The only difference is in the type of VARIABLE HOLDING THE REFERENCE - not the list itself (which is in both cases a List.

It is a matter of style - using IList allows you to easier replace the list with another type implementing IList.

That being said, depending on USAGE you may find out that List is not JUST an IList but also defines OTHER methods. Hence the use of IList may actually be impossible.

Also note that practically for the vast majority of cases it makes no difference - MOST variables will be small and local in use. As such, arguments like "dynamically injecting another type" etc. are irrelevant - there simply is not enough visibility to even mock the created type. Simply as most variables are local.

Comment: I think this is not a matter of coding style. I would argue that there are objective reasons why we should always aim to declare our resources as abstractly as possible, and why is declaring a variable as `IList` is inherently superior than declaring it as a `List` in general. There are exceptions though, but unless one has a very good reason not to support other `IList` implementations, `IList` should automatically be preferred over `List`.

Comment: But coding style is not that the question is about, Also, there are good arguments about using neither but saying "var" and let the compiler sort it out. Which is my fallback and default. My answer ignores coding style because - that is a STYLE, and the question is technical. Coding style would be "vote to close, opinion based".

Comment: I understand your point that you do not intend to make this choice yourself and I also see the rationale. I prefer to determine this myself in most cases. However, the question was about choosing. And the choice is objectively better if IList is preferred unless there are very good reasons for the specific task not to do so.

Comment: THe conce is NOT objectively better if i.e. a coding style determines you should use var. Hence it is a choice and opinion based. In most defined variables there is NO Reason to use the interface definition - they simply never raise to a level where it objectively makes a difference, hence "var" being a lot easier. Hence it being opinion based, as you quite nicely state by stating an opinion that has no basis to overrule a style guide as it objectively makes no difference.

Comment: That's a narrow-minded approach. If you implement a method and you do not see it being necessary to support other possible types, then sooner or later that might suddenly become necessary. While using `var` circumvents the question, it does not change the situation, which is: having an ability is inherently better than not having that ability. The problem is that if someone declares `List` instead of `IList`, then refactors will be needed every time when some other kind of `IList` will suddenly enter the stage. Using `var` is delegating this decision to the compiler.

Comment: The question was about which is the better decision: `IList` or `List`. Frankly, saying that it's a matter of style does not answer the question. Also, if you say that you use `var`. Good for you! But that's also not answering the question. The question is: "which is the better decision"? And your point about using `var` boils down to "let's avoid thinking about it and delegating the decision to the compiler". An answer is either declaring that `IList` is better or that 'List' is better or that their pros and cons equate. Saying that it's a style and let's use `var` is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst `IList<>` may implement all the functionality that `List<>` does, I would generally recommend against `IList<>` at all, and suggest you use either `IEnumerable<>` or `ICollection<>` instead.

`IEnumerable<>` for collections that don't require modification, and `ICollection<>` for collections that you are allowed to modify.

Doing this allows you to swap out the implementation for a more efficient one, just at the point of creation, rather than having to modify every function that references the collection.

Imagine you decide to change a `List<>` to `HashSet<>`.  If your code uses `IList<>` then every reference will have to change, whereas, using `IEnumerable<>` would mean you only make 1 change.

Comment: I would add `IReadOnlyCollection`/`IReadOnlyList` for when you need a count/indexer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer shortly and concisely your excellent question, the answer is **No**. But it is important to understand the reason for it, because this understanding opens the door for abstract thinking. It all boils down to the abstract.

In programming you want to solve as many types of issues as possible with a code as short as possible.

As a result, you need to have data structures that are specific-enough, but as far as that need is met, you should strongly prefer to generalize the solution AMAP.

All `List` objects are also `IList`, but not all objects that are `IList` are also `List`.

So, if your code assumes that your object is a `List`, then it necessarily supports far less cases than if you would be more agnostic and would say that it is an `IList`.

If `IList` properly describes all the methods you might possibly want to call, then it is specific-enough to solve your problem, so it is good. Now, let's suppose that you need to implement a method that searches for an item insidea list. If you implement it so as the parameter it expects is an instance of `List`, then your method will not work for any objects that are `IList`, but not `List`. So, a decision to declare something as a `List` instead of `IList` should always be some strong argument, like, for some well-understood reason, you do not want to support any other `IList`, or something that `List` is capable of but `IList` is not capable of is needed by the source-code section in question.

Answer (score 0):

IList also allows you to mock it in a unit test.